# VS2015 Cordova Sms Plugin Sms.Send doesn't work in Index.JS (ondeviceReady)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to Cordova, any help would be appreciated.

I created a new Cordova Project in VS2015 and added the Cordova SMS plugin to my project (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-sms-plugin).

I added this code to /www/scripts/index.js function onDeviceReady (as per documentiation for plugin):

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
    document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
    document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );

    var numberString = "aoeuaeu";
    var bypassAppChooser = true; 

    //CONFIGURATION
    var options = {
        replaceLineBreaks: false,
        android: {
            intent: 'INTENT'  // send SMS with the native android SMS messaging
        }
    };

    var successSMS = function () { alert('Message sent successfully'); };
    var errorSMS = function (e) { alert('Message Failed:' + e); };
    sms.send("0811231234", "Testing123", options, successSMS, errorSMS);
```

I debug the project using Debug, Android, Ripple - Nexus (Galaxy) selected options.  When I place a breakpoint on the sms.send line of code and I add a watch for 'sms.send', I can see the object exists.

When I single step, this line in sms.js seems to be the last line that executes:

```
// fire
exec(
    success,
    failure,
    'Sms',
    'send', [phone, message, androidIntent, replaceLineBreaks]
);
```

I then get the following error message in Ripple:

**'Sms.send  We seem to be missing some stuff :( What is kinda cool though you can fill in the textarea to pass a json object to the callback you want to execute).'**

I can see that all of the objects in that line is defined (success, failure, phone, message, androidIntent, replaceLineBreaks).  When I 'step into' this line, it continues to execute code in ripple.js, but it becomes hard to follow for a person, since there are no line breaks in this file.

What am I doing wrong? I've read through all the documentation I can find & searched stackoverflow questions and can't seem to find any solutions to the problem.

I've uploaded this entire project (zipped), which can be downloaded at:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwWgTMh-JLbfNHV0MlE5Yk5IZ3M/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Cordova team at Microsoft for helping me with an answer:

"Ripple has the ability to emulate some but not all plugins.  **SMS is not one of the plugins that it can fully emulate.  However, in the message that pops up, you do have the ability to hit the Success or Fail buttons which will report back to the app that it was successful or not in sending the SMS.  While that doesn’t actually send a message, it does let you test your app to see how it behaves for different results.**
I tried the bit of sample code you included in the first email.  In Ripple, I was able to change the alert by hitting the different buttons.

Trying other deployment methods, in both the VS Android Emulator and the Google Emulator they showed failure alert messages that they don’t support SMS messages.  I then launched it on an Android phone device and it said it was successful.

So I believe your options are mainly using Ripple to fake sending of messages or using a device for testing."